# Django: How to refer to a variable if a templatetag returns multiple values

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I access to the variable if a customtemplate tag returns multiple variables?

`templatetags.py`

```
def custom_tag(context):
   # do something
   return A, B
```

and `html`

```
{% load templatetags %}
{% custom_tag as A %} # A used as A
{% custom_tag as B %} # B used as B
```

How can I refer to each variable?

Comment: I haven't tested this but you may be able to use `A.0` and `A.1`. Did you try that?

Comment: I did but it doesn't work. `django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 47: 'custom_tag.0', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your tag doesn't "returns multiple variables", it returns one `(A, B)` tuple, so what you want is:

```
{% custom_tag as AB %}
<p>AB.0 is '{{ AB.0 }}'</p>
<p>AB.1 is '{{ AB.1 }}'</p>
```

Comment: Helpful answer :)